# how to add value quantiy to array

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have the following code, you can go through Class Livewire and View Livewire, I got the desired result but I want to add 1 key to the half to collect, the key I want is quantity, when entering the quantity it will add to collect for me

**Class Livewire**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Medicine;
use App\Models\MedicineCategory;
use Livewire\Component;

class SelectMedicineCategoryTable extends Component
{

    public $columns = ['STT', 'Name', 'Qty', 'Unit'];

    public $medicines;

    public array $selectedMedicineArray = [];

    public $getAllMedicineCategory;
    public $selectMedicineCategoryId = null;

    public $quantity = [];



    public function render()
    {
        $this->getAllMedicineCategory = MedicineCategory::where('status', MedicineCategory::ACTIVE)->get(['id', 'name_medicine']);
        if ($this->selectMedicineCategoryId != '') {
            $this->medicines = Medicine::where('status', Medicine::ACTIVE)->Where('medicine_category_id', $this->selectMedicineCategoryId)->get(['id', 'name', 'unit']);
        } else {
            $this->medicines = [];
        }
        return view('livewire.select-medicine-category-table');
    }
}
```

**View livewire**

```
@forelse ($medicines as $item)
                        <tr>
                            <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" wire:model="selectedMedicineArray"
                                    id="" value="{{ $item }}">
                            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
                            <td><input type="number" wire:model="quantity.{{ $item->id }}" min="1"
                                    id="" value="1">
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ $item->unit }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @empty
                        <tr>
                            <td>Not found result</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforelse
```

**Output current**

```
array ( 0 => '{"id":1,"name":"Padamon","unit":"V\\u0129"}', )
```

**I want Output**

```
array ( 0 => '{"id":1,"name":"Padamon","unit":"V\\u0129", 'quantity:...'}', )
```

Comment: I've never tried livewire but maybe add qty in columns selected in $this->medicines

Comment: Hi @misterdebug, I want to click check the input to get the count in that row for me. Thank you for reading the comment

Comment: thanks all, i found the solution for me